# How to write python regex to find guid in html?

Tags: python, html, regex, html-parsing

How to find guid in following HTML section?

HTML sample:

```
<td>xxxxxxx</td>
<td style="display: none">e3aa8247-354b-e311-b6eb-005056b42341</td>
<td>yyyyyy</td>
<td style="display: none">e3aa8247-354b-e311-b6eb-005056b42342</td>
<td>zzzz</td>
```

Comment: Use a parser to extract the text from the `td`'s then match against it?

Comment: Use BeautifulSoup4 to parse it.

Comment: ids = re.findall( r'<td style="display: none">(.{36})</td>', data, re.I)

Comment: @alexey sure as long as you dont have anything else that is 36 characers long in a hidden td

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an HTML Parser, like that "beautiful" and transparent [`BeautifulSoup`](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) package.

The idea is to locate `td` elements with `xxxxxxx`, `yyyyyy` texts and get the following `td` sibling's text value (assuming `xxxxxxx` and `yyyyyy` are labels you know beforehand):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<tr>
    <td>xxxxxxx</td>
    <td style="display: none">e3aa8247-354b-e311-b6eb-005056b42341</td>
    <td>yyyyyy</td>
    <td style="display: none">e3aa8247-354b-e311-b6eb-005056b42342</td>
    <td>zzzz</td>
</tr>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

print soup.find("td", text="xxxxxxx").find_next_sibling('td').text
```

Prints:

```
e3aa8247-354b-e311-b6eb-005056b42341
```

Comment: while this is the right way in general to parse html/xml ... in this case uuid's always match a specific pattern that fits re just fine :)   (+1 all the same since in general this is definately the right way to parse xml/html)

Comment: @JoranBeasley good point, thanks. Though, we don't know the real input - e.g. there could be multiple uuids and there is the need to distinguish them based on the `xxxxxxx` and `yyyyyy` label

Comment: @alecxe I definately agree... but since he said he just wanted the uuid's this *might* be overkill

Comment: Sometimes I just have no idea what's wrong with the answer and what's happening with all of the downvotes.

Answer (score 4):

```
re.findall("[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}",the_whole_text)
```

this works because uuid's are ALWAYS this format ... in general when parsing html/xml you should actually use an html/xml parser and not re ... since re has a very hard time with nesting